# Liferay Passing a parameter to the jsp used to populate a search-container-column-jsp

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, liferay-6

So I have a search container with results in it.  The last column of this container is a jsp column.  Here is the code for the search container:

```
    <%
    PortletURL postsUrlPaginator = renderResponse.createRenderURL();
    postsUrlPaginator.setParameter( "currentID", Long.toString( currentID ) );
    postsUrlPaginator.setParameter( "jspPage", "/admin/CLAdmin.jsp" );
    postsUrlPaginator.setParameter( "mainTabs", "Categories" );
    %>

    <liferay-ui:search-container emptyResultsMessage = "there-are-no-postings" delta = "5" iteratorURL="<%= postsUrlPaginator %>" curParam="postsUrlPaginator">
        <liferay-ui:search-container-results>
            <%
            List<CLPosting> postings = CLPostingLocalServiceUtil.getLockedPostings( true );
            results = ListUtil.subList( postings, searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd() );
            pageContext.setAttribute( "results", results );
            pageContext.setAttribute( "total", postings.size() );
            %>
        </liferay-ui:search-container-results>

        <liferay-ui:search-container-row 
            className="com.camelslist.posting.model.CLPosting"
            keyProperty="postID"
            modelVar="posting">

            <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text 
                name="postingTitle"
                property="postTitle" />

            <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text 
                name="locked"
                property="locked" />

            <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp
                path="/admin/post/CLAdmin_post_actions.jsp" />

        </liferay-ui:search-container-row>
        <liferay-ui:search-iterator />
    </liferay-ui:search-container>
```

I use a jsp file (CLAdmin_post_actions.jsp) in that last column to generate action buttons for each row returned.  I would like to pass values to that jsp file before it creates those buttons for each row.

```
<%@include file="/init.jsp" %>

<%
ResultRow row = (ResultRow) request.getAttribute( WebKeys.SEARCH_CONTAINER_RESULT_ROW );
CLPosting posting = (CLPosting) row.getObject();
long groupId = themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroupId();
String name = CLPosting.class.getName();
String primeKey = String.valueOf( posting.getPrimaryKey() );
System.out.println( "posting: " + posting.getPostTitle() + " : " + "ID: " + Long.toString( posting.getPrimaryKey() ) );

long currentID = posting.getCategoryID();
CLCategory category = ( currentID != Long.valueOf( 0 ) ) ? CLCategoryLocalServiceUtil.getCLCategory( currentID ) : null;
long parentCatID = ( category != null ) ? category.getParentID() : Long.valueOf( 0 );
%>

<liferay-ui:icon-menu>
    <c:if test = "<%= permissionChecker.hasPermission( groupId, name, primeKey, ActionKeys.DELETE ) %>" >
        <portlet:actionURL name="deletePosting" var="deleteURL">
            <portlet:param name="resourcePrimeKey" value="<%= primeKey %>" />
            <portlet:param name="currentID" value="<%= Long.toString( currentID ) %>" />
        </portlet:actionURL>
        <liferay-ui:icon-delete url="<%= deleteURL.toString() %>" />
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="<%= permissionChecker.hasPermission(groupId, name, primeKey, ActionKeys.VIEW) %>" >
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="<%= permissionChecker.hasPermission(groupId, name, primeKey, ActionKeys.UPDATE) %>" >
        <c:if test="<%= posting.getLocked() == false %>" >
            <portlet:actionURL name="lockPosting" var="lockURL">
                <portlet:param name="resourcePrimeKey" value="<%= primeKey %>" />
                <portlet:param name="currentID" value="<%= Long.toString( currentID ) %>" />
                <portlet:param name="mainTabs" value="Categories" />
                <portlet:param name="lock" value="true" />
            </portlet:actionURL>
            <liferay-ui:icon image="lock" url="<%= lockURL.toString() %>" />
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="<%= posting.getLocked() == true %>" >
            <portlet:actionURL name="lockPosting" var="lockURL">
                <portlet:param name="resourcePrimeKey" value="<%= primeKey %>" />
                <portlet:param name="currentID" value="<%= Long.toString( currentID ) %>" />
                <portlet:param name="mainTabs" value="Categories" />
                <portlet:param name="lock" value="false" />
            </portlet:actionURL>
            <liferay-ui:icon image="unlock" url="<%= lockURL.toString() %>" />
        </c:if>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test = "<%= permissionChecker.hasPermission( groupId, name, primeKey, ActionKeys.PERMISSIONS) %>">
        <liferay-security:permissionsURL
            modelResource="<%= CLPosting.class.getName() %>"
            modelResourceDescription="<%= posting.getPostTitle() %>"
            resourcePrimKey="<%= primeKey %>"
            var="permissionsURL" />
        <liferay-ui:icon image="permissions" url="<%= permissionsURL.toString() %>" />
    </c:if>
</liferay-ui:icon-menu>
```

How would I do so?  Can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered this question myself actually, and the answer is very obvious (for seasoned portlet developers I suppose).

I was attempting to pass the needed values by way of a parameter.  When I used the servlets attribute instead I was able to get the needed value.

Here is what was added to the above code to make this answer a bit more clear:

```
<%
//NEW LINES ADDED
String mainTabs = ParamUtil.getString( request, "mainTabs", "Categories" );
request.setAttribute( "mainTabs", mainTabs );

PortletURL postsUrlPaginator = renderResponse.createRenderURL();
postsUrlPaginator.setParameter( "currentID", Long.toString( currentID ) );
postsUrlPaginator.setParameter( "jspPage", "/admin/CLAdmin.jsp" );
postsUrlPaginator.setParameter( "mainTabs", "Categories" );
%>
//... additional code not shown
```

then in the CLAdmin_actions.jsp add the following line at the top to retrieve our value:

```
String mainTabs = (String) request.getAttribute( "mainTabs" );
```

Comment: Could you please explain this a little more? I am not so experienced in portlet technology/liferay. I am using liferay 6.1.1 GA2

Comment: I can.  The above example I needed to send information off to a JSP.  You can store information for such a task as so: request.setAttribute( "mainTabs", mainTabs ); then you can do something like the following to retrieve the needed information in the JSP that requires it: String mainTabs = (String) request.getAttribute( "mainTabs" );

Comment: Thanks, but I used another way, we can set attribute of  liferay-ui:search-container as searchContainer="<%=sc%>" and define sc as 

renderResponse.createRenderURL().setParameter("param", "value");
SearchContainer sc = new SearchContainer(renderRequest, null, null, SearchContainer.DEFAULT_CUR_PARAM, delta, current, null, null);